# Using ForLoop Container to do inserts in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Here's what I want to do - I have a Data Flow Task which a simple OleDb source and destination. The OleDb source is a sql query like

```
select * from xyzTable where Id = "UserVariable" (integer type variable)
```

I want to put this DFT in a ForLoop Container and provide the value of this "UserVariable" from the ForLoop Container.

I have made a variable like "UserVariable" as Int32 and initialized it as 1 in the ForLoop configuration, I have something like "UserVariable <= 30" as the "EvalExpression" and "UserVariable = UserVariable + 1" as the "AssignExpression". 
Now, how do I pass this "UserVariable" in the DFT?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreach Loop Container For Data Flow Task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008637/foreach-loop-container-for-data-flow-task)

Answer (score 0):

In the OLE DB Source, I would code the SQL like this:

`select * from xyzTable where Id = ?`

Then choose the Parameters button and specify the UserVariable.